How to download multiple files from Google Cloud Storage bucket and save each into its separate folder
I'm trying to download a batch of about 50 files from a Google Cloud Storage bucket. I have a bucket that contains multiple files. I can search and filter using the user interface until I have the files selected that I need to download. I can get the terminal download command for each and then plan to use gsutil -m cp/gcloud storage cp to download it to my local storage (HPC). Is there a way to create individual folders for each of these files and put them in these folders as I download them?
I know that there is a command using gsutil -m cp to download select multiple files from the bucket to local storage. Not sure if gcloud storage cp works similarly.

gsutil is the original Google Cloud CLI for Cloud Storage and predates gcloud. gcloud has only recently added gcloud storage commands to replicate/replace gsutil. So gsutil is still the more fully featured but it's become "potatoes potatoes". Your question is unclear. The gsutil|gcloud storage commands allow you to download multiple files to one local folder (but not several). You would want to generate multiple gsutil|gcloud storage commands to download multiple files to multiple folders. This should be straightforward using scripting or one of the Cloud Storage SDKs

Got it! My question was about how to download each file into a folder corresponding to its name using the gcloud storage command, but I solved that issue through scripting, as you mentioned. Thanks!
